# In Python, is it possible to restrict the type of a function parameter to two possible types?

Tags: python

I try to restrict the 'parameter' type to be int or list like the function 'f' below. However, Pycharm does not show a warning at the line f("weewfwef") about wrong parameter type, which means this (parameter : [int, list]) is not correct.

In Python, is it possible to restrict the type of a python function parameter to two possible types?

```
def f(parameter : [int, list]):
    if len(str(parameter)) <= 3:
        return 3
    else:
        return [1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f("weewfwef")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term you're looking for is a [union type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).

```
from typing import Union

def f(parameter: Union[int, list]):
  ...
```

`Union` is not limited to two types. If you ever have a value which is one of several known types, but you can't necessarily know which one, you can use `Union[...]` to encapsulate that information.

Answer (score 2):

Try out `typing.Union`

```
from typing import Union
def f(parameter : Union[int,list]):
    if len(str(parameter)) <= 3:
        return 3
    else:
        return [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is no such strict type checking, that's why it follows duck typing https://realpython.com/lessons/duck-typing/

```
def f(parameter : [int, list]):
    if not(type(parameter) in [list, int]):
        raise ValueError("Invalid Input type")
    if len(str(parameter)) <= 3:
        return 3
    else:
        return [1]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def f(parameter : [int, list]):
    if type(parameter) == (int or list):
        if len(str(parameter)) <= 3:
            return 3
        else:
            return [1]
    else:
        raise ValueError # You can use other error if you want to

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f("weewfwef"))
```

use `type()` to check it's type and use if statement and raise an error